# Как происходит импорт модулей

Tags: python, модули

Есть вопрос, за ним не стоит конкретного кода, просто интересно. Допустим, у нас есть главная программа(файл) main.py, из него с помощью import мы импортируем sub.py и из каждого из них мы импортируем один и тот же файл module.py. Как это будет выглядеть?[image: ...]
Если мы из main внесём изменения в module(может переменную поменять или типа того) сможет ли sub уловить эти изменения?

module.py:

```
varible = 0
```

main.py:

```
import module
module.varible = 5

import sub
```

sub.py:

```
import module
print(module.varible)
```

Проще говоря, что выведет sub?

Comment: Во-первых, почему бы не попробовать, даже есть конкретный код? Во-вторых, будет `5`, все модули выполняются один раз при первом импорте, потом только имена подтягиваются.

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал получилось 5